# Query string lost on redirection with keycloak as Broker and ADFS as IDP

Tags: java, keycloak, adfs

I have integrated keycloak with a web application using the java adapter (no changes on the Angular frontend, just backend)
We have several clients in our aplication, and we have the option of chosing among them through a query string on the URL. For example:

https://localhost:8443/myapp/#/login?client=TEST-CLIENT

Neither using Keycloak as an IDP, neither using ADFS as an IDP, the query string is lost, so I don't get to the correct client (TEST-CLIENT in this case) when redirected.

Any idea how to keep the whole url in order to make it work?

**EDIT**:

Taking out the # parameter I get the same result:

https://localhost:8443/myapp?client=TEST-CLIENT

Comment: This is exactly why the `#/` pattern is broken--nothing after the `#` is actually part of the URI.